# Check for duplicate items before pushing

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, duplicates

Good morning,

I'm wanting to push new items to an array (which we can do) but before pushing check for duplicates to prevent duplicating items within the array.

I've tried this **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/u8Fuk/10/)**, unsuccessfully I haven't managed to get this working with our code.

If anyone know of a better solution or can see where we are going wrong please let us know asap.
Thank you.

** JS **

```
 $scope.Products = $scope.$storage.Products == undefined ? [] : $scope.$storage.Products;
 $scope.logItem = function($index, brandName, partNumber, productName, amount) {

     $scope.newItem = {
         Brand: brandName,
         Part: partNumber,
         Product: productName,
         Amount: amount
     };

     var duplicateItem = $scope.Products.reduce(function(previous, i) {
         if ($scope.newItem === i) return true;
         return previous
     }, false);

     if (duplicateItem) {
         alert("Already Logged");
     } else {
         alert("Item Logged");
         $scope.Products.push($scope.newItem);
         $scope.$storage.Products = $scope.Products;
     }


 }
```

** FIX **

```
$scope.Products = $scope.$storage.Products == undefined ? [] : $scope.$storage.Products;
$scope.logItem = function($index, brandName, partNumber, productName, amount) {
    $scope.newItem = {
        Brand: brandName,
        Part: partNumber,
        Product: productName,
        Amount: amount
    };
    var isDuplicate = false;
    $scope.Products.forEach(function(element) {
        if (JSON.stringify(element) === JSON.stringify($scope.newItem)) {
            isDuplicate = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (!isDuplicate) {
        alert("Item Logged");
        $scope.Products.push($scope.newItem);
        $scope.$storage.Products = $scope.Products;
    } else {
        alert("Already Logged");
    };

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this

```
$scope.Products.forEach(function (element) {
    if (JSON.stringify(element) === JSON.stringify($scope.newItem)) {
        isDuplicate = true;
        return false;
    }
});
```

[Look fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sy9cst74/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You can always check if it's safe to push to an array before pushing on to it.

```
if ($scope.ITEMS.indexOf(ITEM) == -1) {
  // SAFE
  $scope.ITEMS.push(ITEM);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/u8Fuk/24/ .

You can use the `unique` filter. for that you need to add dependecy for angularui,
then you can simply do

```
ng-repeat="item in items | unique:'item' "
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use _.reject or _.filter functions in underscore.js to prevent the duplicate values based on conditions